# How to format datetime in python as date is doing?

Tags: python, bash, date

In the shell:

```
$ date
Do 27. Jun 15:13:13 CEST 2019
```

In python:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 27, 15, 14, 51, 314560)
>>> a = datetime.now()
>>> a.strftime("%Y%m%d")
'20190627'
```

What is the format specifier needed to get the *exactly same output* as `date`, including evaluation of the locale settings?

Comment: `datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")` ?

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior? Note that I get `Thu 27 Jun 2019 14:18:56 BST` on OS X - looks like the *order* may change, which would be complicated to deal with. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: see page [strftime.org](http://strftime.org/)

Comment: try `a.strftime("%c")`

Comment: What is the `Do` at the start of `Do 27. Jun 15:13:13 CEST 2019`?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay It's the abbreviated local weekday, "Donnerstag" (thursday in German).

Comment: @jonrsharpe "what are you trying to achieve?" As said, print the date exactly as the `date` program would do. Is that not a worthy goal?

Comment: @EdChum exactly, thanks!

Comment: That's the [Y](http://xyproblem.info/), what's the X? What's the underlying goal? What are the constraints? If you really want exactly what date gives, for example, you could shell out to it instead of trying to recreate it in Python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Currently my implementation is using `date` by shelling out. This can not be unit tested (at least with `freezegun`). I want to provide a pure-python implementation of the function generating the date so that I can unit test it. But these are just (boring) details. My goal is to generate the same output as `date` for reasons XYZ. Trust me, I know what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the [locale](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) module

Playing in the shell:

```
$ date
Thu Jun 27 10:01:03 EDT 2019
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 date
jeu. juin 27 10:01:12 EDT 2019
```

In python

```
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 20 2019, 20:27:34) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().strftime("%c")
'Thu Jun 27 10:03:13 2019'
```

Hmm, I expected python to respect my environment. Let's force the issue:

```
>>> import locale
>>> import os
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, os.environ['LC_ALL'])
'fr_FR.UTF-8'
>>> datetime.now().strftime("%c")
'jeu. 27 juin 2019 10:04:48 '
```

Ah.

---

Reading a little further into the locale docs, I see

> Initially, when a program is started, the locale is the C locale, no matter what the user’s preferred locale is. The program must explicitly say that it wants the user’s preferred locale settings by calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')`.

Comment: Exactly! The `%c` specifier is what I was looking for. Configuring the locale is an added bonus. Thanks!

Comment: `os.environ['LC_TIME']` would be another option in case 'LC_ALL' is not defined, as on the Linux machine I'm using in this moment.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to get your own string format.

in your case you want:

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

print(now.strftime("%a %d. %b %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"))
```

**NOTE:** how the day/month name are printed will be affected by your machine's current locale. you can set a custom datetime locale and timezone if you need specific ones.

Comment: I know that I can use `strftime`(it is right there in my question). What I am looking for is what format specifier might produce the same output as `date`, respecting the locale. You format specifier will only work in the german locale (the dot in `%d.` is a feature of the german language)

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
now=datetime.now()
year=now.strftime("%Y")
print("Year:",year)
month=now.strftime("%m")
print("Month:",month)
day=now.strftime("%d")
print("Day:",day)
time=now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Time:",time)
date_time=now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
print("date and time:",date_time)
```

output:
Year: 2019
Month: 06
Day: 27
Time: 21:19:33
date and time: 06/27/2019, 21:19:33

Comment: Before answering any question, try to understand what exactly the user has asked. Did you take a look at the output of $ date ?